# SAS - PROC SQL: two tables: each one column distinct value, left join

Tags: sql, sas, left-join, proc

I have a table with distinct dates YYYYMMDD from 20000101 until 20001231 and a table with distinct time points (HH:MM:SS) from 09:30:00 until 16:00:00.

I would like to create a (left) join where every day gets repeated 391 times assigned with each time point. That looks to me like a left join, however, I do not have any id's for joining.

```
date          time
20000101    09:30:00
20000101    09:31:00
20000101    ...
20000101    ...
20000101    15:59:00
20000101    16:00:00
20000102    09:30:00
20000102    ...
20000102    16:00:00
```

how would the respective code look like (if there is no explicit common primary key to join on)?

```
PROC SQL;
   SELECT DISTINCT a.date, b.time
   FROM table_1 a, table_1 b (both information are in the same table)
   ;
QUIT;
```

Just as background: there are days that are "shorter" / less than 391 observation points. However, I would like to make sure every day has 391 observation points, just filled up with missing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show all observed times (over all dates) for each date, as well as maintaining original satellite information I would use a reflexive cross join of the combinatoric columns for the basis of a reflexive left join.

Consider this sample data generator.  It simulates the case of data being gathered at different intervals (every 10 or 20 minutes) on different days.

```
data have;
  do i = 1 to 5;
    date = '01-apr-2018'd + (i-1);
    do j = 0 to 4;
      time = '12:00't + (mod(i,2)+1) * 600 * j;  * every other day sample at 1o or 20 minute interval;
      x = ceil ( 25 * ranuni(123) );
      OUTPUT;
    end;
  end;
  format date yymmdd10. time time8.;
  keep date time x;
run;
```

SQl is used to cross join the distinct dates and times and then the original data is left joined to the cross join.

```
proc sql;
  create table cross_as_left_basis 
  as
  select 
    cross.date
  , cross.time
  , have.x
  from
    ( select distinct dates.date, times.time
      from       have as dates
      cross join have as times
    ) as
    cross
  left join 
    have 
  on 
    cross.date = have.date
    and cross.time = have.time
  ;
```

Have is

```
      date        time     x

2018-04-01    12:00:00    19
              12:20:00     9
              12:40:00     5
              13:00:00    23
              13:20:00     9

2018-04-02    12:00:00     6
              12:10:00    20
              12:20:00    10
              12:30:00     4
              12:40:00     5

2018-04-03    12:00:00    20
              12:20:00    11
              12:40:00    25
              13:00:00     7
              13:20:00    18

2018-04-04    12:00:00    14
              12:10:00    14
              12:20:00    22
              12:30:00     4
              12:40:00    22

2018-04-05    12:00:00    17
              12:20:00    20
              12:40:00    18
              13:00:00     9
              13:20:00    14
```

The join result is

```
      date        time     x

2018-04-01    12:00:00    19
              12:10:00     .
              12:20:00     9
              12:30:00     .
              12:40:00     5
              13:00:00    23
              13:20:00     9

2018-04-02    12:00:00     6
              12:10:00    20
              12:20:00    10
              12:30:00     4
              12:40:00     5
              13:00:00     .
              13:20:00     .

2018-04-03    12:00:00    20
              12:10:00     .
              12:20:00    11
              12:30:00     .
              12:40:00    25
              13:00:00     7
              13:20:00    18

2018-04-04    12:00:00    14
              12:10:00    14
              12:20:00    22
              12:30:00     4
              12:40:00    22
              13:00:00     .
              13:20:00     .

2018-04-05    12:00:00    17
              12:10:00     .
              12:20:00    20
              12:30:00     .
              12:40:00    18
              13:00:00     9
              13:20:00    14
```

Answer (score 2):

You need Cartesian Product since you want to generate all combinations of date and time. So to produce such result you need `CROSS JOIN` in which you don't have to give any JOIN Condition.

Try the below query:

```
PROC SQL;
   SELECT a.date, b.time
   FROM table_1 a
   CROSS JOIN
   table_1 b
   GROUP BY a.date, b.time 
   ;
QUIT;
```

**OR**

```
PROC SQL;
       SELECT a.date, b.time
       FROM (SELECT date FROM table_1) a
       CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT time FROM table_1) b
       GROUP BY a.date, b.time 
       ;
QUIT;
```

For more info on `CROSS JOIN` Follow the below link:

> http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/fedsqlref/67364/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1q7agzgxs9ik5n1p7k3sdft0u9u.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can do either a `Left Join` or `Join`  and add `Where 1=1` this will create the Cartesian Product for you:

Code:

```
proc sql;
 create table want as
  select t1.date, t2.time
  from t1 left join t2 on 1=1
  order by date, time;
quit;
```